# In Login page of web application, I have allowed drag and drop of any text. Is it vulnerable to XSS attack?

Tags: penetration-test, xss

Will I need to add any attribute to restrict drag and drop of any file?

Comment: Can we assume just a normal login page consisting of nothing more than a form with a "username" text field, a "password" password field and a "submit" button which performs a HTTPS POST to an url or is there more behind it?

Comment: Yes, Consider simple UI of "Login" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSS attack is performed by injecting malicious code to be displayed to another user.

To use a standard login form for an XSS attack, you would need the malicious code to be in the username - the only thing likely to be shown to other users.
But how the username-with-malicious payload got in there isn't relevant, so it is not inherent to the fact that you use drag-and-drop.

Allowing a username that consists of a large amount of text (for example, the contents of a file) would make it easier to perform this type of XSS attack in a username. So you'll want to check the username against it.

That being said, usernames are often limited in the length they're allowed to have. This makes them unlikely attack vectors. If you're running some kind of forum, users signature lines and forum posts are more likely places to contain an XSS attack.

Comment: Will I need to restict only drag and drop and username length to avoid XSS attack?

Comment: Limiting username length makes XSS harder but not necessarily impossible. And works only for the username. I suggest that instead, you have a look at the [OWASP page about XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), and their [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).